# Insert JSON document to row in MySQL using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, ado.net

I want to insert a JSON document to a varchar column in my MySQL database. I am developing my application in ASP.NET and c#. I use the following command:

```
MySqlCommand cmnd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE sharding_conf SET config = \"" + json + "\" WHERE id = 1");
```

The problem is that the JSON document also contains the " character so I get an error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

How can I insert a JSON document? - Just note that I intend to de-serialize it when I read the data back from the database and put it in an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameterized queries in place of inline query. so using:

```
MySqlCommand cmnd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE sharding_conf SET config = @config WHERE id = 1");
cmnd.Parameters.Add("@config",json);
```

I don't know if @ is used in my sql or ? but that's how it can be fixed.